# How to share the value of Class in different python scripts?

Tags: python, class, variables, popen

I have 3 python scripts:

```
main.py
sub.py
shared.py
```

In shared.py I define a Class called 'myClass':

```
myClass.x
myClass.y
myClass.z
```

In main.py use Popen to run sub.py:

```
Popen(['python', 'sub.py', myClass)]
```

This code don't work. How I can share myClass between process?

Comment: Can you do `from sub.py import myClass`?

Comment: You can't share between different processes. If you want to use a class in another script, use the `import` command.

Comment: `import` command import the structure of myClass not the contents.

Comment: what information do you actually want to share between the processes? Know that sharing information between processes isn't very easy.